# How to make a automatic sequence of dates (incrementing month) that repeats X times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaUhT.png)

What I need is for the right column (B) to repeat and be automatically filled with those dates (mm/yyyy, from 01/2023 to 12/2023) whenever there is data on the left column (A)

I'm using a formula to increment the months 12 times starting from 01/2023:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(EDATE(DATE(2023;0;1);SEQUENCE(12;1;1;1)))`

but I can't figure out how to make that range repeatable with the conditional of column A not being empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to the following formula-

```
=MAP(INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(36),12)),LAMBDA(x,IF(x=0,DATE(2023,12,1),DATE(2023,x,1))))
```

[image]

Comment: This worked really well! But I made a change to the `SEQUENCE` function based on @Codebabbler suggestion, instead of using a set amount of rows I needed it be conditional to the left column, so I added the function `COUNTA` and it worked perfectly.

The formula looks like this now:

`=MAP(INDEX(MOD(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A)),12)),LAMBDA(x,IF(x=0,DATE(2023,12,1),DATE(2023,x,1))))`

Comment: @skablnss Glad to know. If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(EDATE(DATE(2023,0,1),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A),1,1,1)))
```

From your original formula, I have replaced the number of rows in the `SEQUENCE` function with `COUNTA` which counts the number of values in a dataset.

[image: Screenshot]